# Selecting an offset range after finding a cell that matches the value of another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having issues with my code as it's returning the error upon running the code "Object variable or With block variable not set". I've tried finding a fix for this and think it has something to do with the Set command but I can't figure it out. I'm not that good with VBA code yet. Still learning.

```
Sub FindAndDeleteRange()

Dim rFound As Range
Dim newRange As Range

RowNmbrSumDel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("W3").Value + 2
Set rFound = Range("A:A").Find(What:=Range("R2").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set newRange = Range(rFound, rFound.Offset(RowNmbrSumDel, 10))

If rFound Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Cannot find that year to delete." & Chr(10) & "Please check you have entered correctly.", , "Error"
ElseIf Not rFound Is Nothing Then
newRange.Select
End If

End Sub
```

As you can hopefully see, I'm wanting it to find the value from `R2` somewhere in `column A`. If it does then to select the range defined in `newRange`, but if not to show the error `Msgbox`. I really don't know how wrong it is. I'm sure I had it somewhat working before I added the msgbox to it but can't remember how it was. Any help is appreciated.

Also: I know its a delete sub. I'm just trying through with selecting. It will be more changed but I need to get past this error first.

Comment: Put the line `Set newRange = Range(rFound, rFound.Offset(RowNmbrSumDel, 10))` in the `ElseIf` part of `If rFound Is Nothing Then` and try again... Just before the `newRange.Select`

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much. So simple yet went beyond me. Cheers. Do you want to put it as an actual answer so I can close it and give it to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Set newRange = Range(rFound, rFound.Offset(RowNmbrSumDel, 10))

You are getting that error because `rFound` is nothing and you are trying it use `rFound` to set `newRange`

Move the line in the `ElseIf` section. You will also have to do that for `newRange` as well.

Also avoid the use of `.Select`. You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
Sub FindAndDeleteRange()
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim newRange As Range

    RowNmbrSumDel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("W3").Value + 2

    Set rFound = Range("A:A").Find(What:=Range("R2").Value, _
                 LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If rFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cannot find that year to delete." & Chr(10) & _
        "Please check you have entered correctly.", , "Error"
    ElseIf Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        Set newRange = Range(rFound, rFound.Offset(RowNmbrSumDel, 10))

        '~~> Now Check if newRange is not nothing
        If Not newRange Is Nothing Then
            With newRange
                '~~> Do Something
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "Cannot find.. your message here..."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```